# is jquery replace javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can jquery replace javascript

Comment: No, jQuery is a DOM toolkit build in and for JavaScript. You NEED JavaScript.

Comment: yes,see this http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif{from http://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm}

Comment: Yes of course it can :-)

Comment: *facepalm*  That is all.

Answer (score 3):

Unless somebody writes a new scripting language (other than Javascript), creates a browser that uses it, and ports the entire jQuery library to that new scripting language...then no.

jQuery is built on top of Javascript. jQuery is not a scripting language in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, jQuery is written in the language Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery **is** javascript insofar as jQuery is simply a re-usable library of javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

jquery is javascript, jquery can't work without javascript

Comment: Not true, javascript can exist without jQuery.

Comment: JavaScript can exist very happily without jQuery

Comment: javascript can exist without jQuery, no?

Comment: that came out wrong edited to be what I meant

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is written in javascript and provides higher-level, i.e. more abstract, functionality with respect to the DOM and changing element properties and behaviors. jQuery has much momentum in the marketplace and as a result of its wide adoption, fewer and fewer sites will be coded directly in "raw" javascript and more and more and more will be coded using the intermediary of the jQuery API.   So while it is of course technically accurate to say that jQuery isn't going to replace javascript (just as the blacktop in the parking lot cannot replace the ground beneath it) in another sense jQuery *is* going to replace javascript: jQuery is very likely to become the *de facto* "abstraction layer" for the DOM and for the routine control structures provided by the javascript language.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a framework (program) written in JavaScript. It just provide additional facilities, like any other library.